# Creating Perpendicular lines between groundwater contours and flow direction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have groundwater contours and flow direction arrows, each in their own feature class. I'm wondering if there is a way to draw the flow direction arrows so that they cross over the groundwater contours at a perpendicular angle?

[image]